# Python Select random film from json by film type

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, random

```
import random
import json

# user_input = input('')

with open('robot.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for film in data['films']:
    print(film["title"], film["category"])
```

In the code above, I want to add a user input that allows a user to specify the genre of film and using that response, retrieve a random selection from its respective category that is contained within the 'robot.json' file.

I can't seem to get random.choice to work, but that program will print all the entries in the json.

I am new to this, so I keep getting stuck in the weeds. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

`Random.choice` "choose a random element from a non-empty sequence".
Using a dict to group films by their category should be helpful.

```
import random
import json
from collections import defaultdict


with open('robot.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

d = defaultdict(list)                   
for film in data['films']:
    d[film["category"]].append(film)    # group films by category

user_input = input('')
if user_input in d:
    choice = random.choice(d[user_input])
    print(choice)
else:                                   # invalid input
    print('Unknown Category')
```

With this example file,

```
{
  "films": [
    { "title": "A", "category": "comedy" },
    { "title": "B", "category": "comedy" }
  ]
}
```

the script would work like `comedy ==> A or B, horror ==> Unknown Category`

Comment: So, I am getting a NameError: name 'comedy' is not defined, when I enter it into the user input. So the random sorting needs to be achieved by accessing the "category" tag in the JSON and then it needs to return a title. I apologize if that's obvious but I am also trying to work this out in my head.. 

I appreciate the feedback and if you have additional ideas please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: @Swan Sorry but I didn't get where `comedy` comes from. The `else` statement are supposed to safeguard unknown category. `NameError` happens when variable name does not exist. Maybe you can show me which line the error is raised?

Comment: python .\robot_test.py
comedy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\robot_test.py", line 13, in <module>
    user_input = input('')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'comedy' is not defined

Comment: @Swan Looks like Python2 you are using. Please use `raw_input` because `input` evaluates input as code and then there is no variable called `comedy`. Or switch to Python3 where `input` works as desired.

Comment: It works! I tried both options! Thank you! Do you know how I can route this through an HTML container?

Comment: @Swan Do you mean web app container? Depends on which you are using. Some communicates through stdio `import sys; sys.stdin.readline()`. It should be configurable within your container.

Comment: I do appreciate the help. I upvoted this. Yes, a web app container. I need to present this to a class, so having a visual interface that isn't my terminal would be nice. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Swan If working with Python, `flask` is a easy-to-handle web framework. Find an HTML template to make a nice UI and let `flask` handle all the communication between webpages and python backend.

Comment: Thank you again! I couldn't figure out flask yet so I will have some more questions but I was under a deadline so I needed to get the MVP out. Would you be willing to discuss this at a later date?

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random
import requests
import webbrowser

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/chart/top', headers=headers)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
tbody=soup.find_all('td',class_='titleColumn')
######
######
while True:
    randomNmber=random.randint(0,len(tbody))
    nameOfMovie=tbody[randomNmber].find('a').text
    year=tbody[randomNmber].find('span').text
    link='https://www.imdb.com'+tbody[randomNmber].find('a').get('href')
    reso=requests.get(link,headers=headers)
    soupmv=BeautifulSoup(reso.text, 'html.parser')
    trailer=soupmv.find('a',class_='slate_button prevent-ad-overlay video-modal').get('href')
    trailerLINK='https://www.imdb.com'+trailer
    print('how about: '+nameOfMovie+' '+year) print('trailer link: '+trailerLINK) wht=input('go to trailer hit "go" new one hit "enter" exit(any key)') if wht=='go' or wht=='A': webbrowser.open(trailerLINK) if wht == '': continue else: break
```

Visit https://www.icodes.tech/2021/02/pick-random-movie-with-a-script-python.html